# What are Context-Free Grammars and Backus Naur Form?

Tags: syntax, context-free-grammar, bnf

Can someone please explain in layman's terms:

1. what a context-free grammar is?
2. what Backus Naur Form is?
3. How to use this notation?
4. How to do string derivation?
5. How to describe language syntax?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A context-free grammar (CFG) G is a quadruple (V, Σ, R, S) where

- V: a set of non-terminal symbols
- Σ: a set of terminals (V ∩ Σ = Ǿ)
- R: a set of rules (R: V → (V U Σ)*)
- S: a start symbol

***Example of CFG:***

- V = {q, f,}
- Σ = {0, 1}
- R = {q → 11q, q → 00f, f → 11f, f → ε}
- S=q
- (R= {q → 11q | 00f, f → 11f | ε })

As far as I understand, Backus Naur Form (BNF) is another way of representing the things that are shown in the Context-Free Grammar (CFG)

***Example of BNF:***

[number] ::= [digit] | [number] [digit]

[digit] ::= 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9

which can be read as something like:
"a number is a digit, or any number followed by an extra digit"
(which is a contorted but precise way of saying that a number consists of one or more digits)
"a digit is any one of the characters 0, 1, 2, ... 9"

***Difference:***

Notation of these two representations are a bit different, i-e

--> equals ::=

| equals or

there must be some other differences but to be honest I don't know any other :)

***String Derivation:***

Let S be the start" symbol

- S --> A, the initial state
- A --> 0A
- A --> 1B
- A --> ?
- B --> 1B
- B --> ?

***Example of String Derivation:***

Does this grammar generate the string 000111?
yes, it does!

- S --> A
- A --> 0A
- 0A --> 00A
- 00A --> 000A
- 000A --> 0001B
- 0001B --> 00011B
- 00011B --> 000111

that's all from my side, I too am working on it and will surely share if I come to know anymore details about defining the language syntax.

cheers!

Comment: In your derivations what are A and B. Not seen it done that way before.

Comment: AFAIK `A` and `B` are `non-terminal`, whereas the `0`s and `1`s are 'terminals'

Answer (score 4):

A context-free grammar is a type of formal language.
Backus Naur form is a specification language for this type of grammar. It is used to describe language syntax.
You should read:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language_theory
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form